# How do I get python-markdown to additionally "urlify" links when formatting plain text?

Tags: python, django, markdown

Markdown is a great tool for formatting plain text into pretty html, but it doesn't turn plain-text links into URLs automatically. Like this one:

http://www.google.com/

How do I get markdown to add  tags to URLs when I format a block of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get superjoe30's regular expression to compile, so I adapted his solution to convert plain URLs (within Markdown text) to be Markdown compatible.

The modified filter:

```
urlfinder = re.compile('^(http:\/\/\S+)')
urlfinder2 = re.compile('\s(http:\/\/\S+)')
@register.filter('urlify_markdown')
def urlify_markdown(value):
    value = urlfinder.sub(r'<\1>', value)
    return urlfinder2.sub(r' <\1>', value)
```

Within the template:

```
<div>
    {{ content|urlify_markdown|markdown}}
</div>
```

Comment: (If you are interested on a refined regular expression that matches many real-life URLs, in the code above you can use the one from here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: will not work with content containing html anchors, also will not work when links are present inside code blocks.

Answer (score 6):

You could write an extension to markdown. Save this code as mdx_autolink.py

```
import markdown
from markdown.inlinepatterns import Pattern

EXTRA_AUTOLINK_RE = r'(?<!"|>)((https?://|www)[-\w./#?%=&]+)'

class AutoLinkPattern(Pattern):

    def handleMatch(self, m):
        el = markdown.etree.Element('a')
        if m.group(2).startswith('http'):
            href = m.group(2)
        else:
            href = 'http://%s' % m.group(2)
        el.set('href', href)
        el.text = m.group(2)
        return el

class AutoLinkExtension(markdown.Extension):
    """
    There's already an inline pattern called autolink which handles 
    <http://www.google.com> type links. So lets call this extra_autolink 
    """

    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        md.inlinePatterns.add('extra_autolink', 
            AutoLinkPattern(EXTRA_AUTOLINK_RE, self), '<automail')

def makeExtension(configs=[]):
    return AutoLinkExtension(configs=configs)
```

Then use it in your template like this:

```
{% load markdown %}

(( content|markdown:'autolink'))
```

Update:

I've found an issue with this solution: When markdown's standard link syntax is used and the displayed portion matches the regular expression, eg:

```
[www.google.com](http://www.yahoo.co.uk)
```

strangely becomes:
    [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

But who'd want to do that anyway?!

Comment: > But who'd want to do that anyway?!

Phishers?

Answer (score 4):

Best case scenario, edit the markdown and just put < > around the URLs. This will make the link clickable. Only problem is it requires educating your users, or whoever writes the markdown.

Answer (score 3):

There's an extra for this in python-markdown2:

http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/wiki/LinkPatterns

Comment: This is now at https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2 and its `link-patterns` extra (documented in the Wiki) did exactly this, and keeps existing HTML and Markdown format links as they are. Nothing else I tried worked satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a feature of Markdown -- what you should do is run a post-processor against the text looking for a URL-like pattern. There's a good example in the [Google app engine example code](http://google-app-engine-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cccwiki/wiki.py) -- see the `AutoLink` transform.

Comment: The post processor will have to ignore links inside <code> and <pre>

Answer (score 2):

I was using the [Django framework](http://www.djangoproject.com/), which has a filter called urlize, which does exactly what I wanted. However, it only works on plain text, so I couldn't pass is through the output of markdown. I followed [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to create a custom filter called urlify2 which works on html, and passed the text through this filter:

```
<div class="news_post">
  {% autoescape off %}
    {{ post.content|markdown|urlify2}}
  {% endautoescape %}
</div>
```

The urlify2.py filter:

```
from django import template
import re

register = template.Library()

urlfinder = re.compile("([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}|((news|telnet|nttp|file|http|ftp|https)://)|(www|ftp)[-A-Za-z0-9]*\\.)[-A-Za-z0-9\\.]+):[0-9]*)?/[-A-Za-z0-9_\\$\\.\\+\\!\\*\\(\\),;:@&=\\?/~\\#\\%]*[^]'\\.}>\\),\\\"]")

@register.filter("urlify2")
def urlify2(value):
    return urlfinder.sub(r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', value)
```

Comment: This will urlify links inside code blocks which is not wanted, also will double-urlify html anchors.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is almost a decade old, but markdown-urlize covers every possible use case I could think of including not requiring http(s):// before a url, leaving the parenthesis in `(google.com)`, removing the angle brackets from `<google.com>`, ignoring urls in code blocks, and more I hadn't thought of:

https://github.com/r0wb0t/markdown-urlize

There's no pip install, but you can wget this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r0wb0t/markdown-urlize/master/mdx_urlize.py

and then either put the above file on the python path (first option) or not (second option) and then use one of the following:

```
markdown.markdown(text, extensions=['urlize'], safe_mode=True)
markdown.markdown(text, extensions=['path.to.mdx_urlize'], safe_mode=True)
```