# replace URLs in text with links to URLs

Tags: python, regex, url, hyperlink

Using Python I want to replace all URLs in a body of text with links to those URLs, like what Gmail does.
Can this be done in a one liner regular expression?

Edit: by body of text I just meant plain text - no HTML

Comment: One would assume though, that you are *creating* HTML, since plain text has no special notation of a link vs. a URL.  So you would convert `http://blah.com/page/ref/something?param=foo` found in your plain text to `<a href="http://blah.com/page/ref/something?param=foo">http://blah.com/page/ref/something?param=foo</a>`, yes?

Comment: yes, it will then be inserted into a HTML document

Comment: the answers so far have focussed on matching the URL. How about replacing it with the link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can load the document up with a DOM/HTML parsing library ( see html5lib ), grab all text nodes, match them against a regular expression and replace the text nodes with a regex replacement of the URI with anchors around it using a PCRE such as:

```
/(https?:[;\/?\\@&=+$,\[\]A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\!\~\*\'\(\)%][\;\/\?\:\@\&\=\+\$\,\[\]A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\!\~\*\'\(\)%#]*|[KZ]:\\*.*\w+)/g
```

I'm quite sure you can scourge through and find some sort of utility that does this, I can't think of any off the top of my head though.

Edit: Try using the answers here: [How do I get python-markdown to additionally "urlify" links when formatting plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203859/how-do-i-get-python-markdown-to-additionally-urlify-links-when-formatting-plain)

```
import re

urlfinder = re.compile("([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}|((news|telnet|nttp|file|http|ftp|https)://)|(www|ftp)[-A-Za-z0-9]*\\.)[-A-Za-z0-9\\.]+):[0-9]*)?/[-A-Za-z0-9_\\$\\.\\+\\!\\*\\(\\),;:@&=\\?/~\\#\\%]*[^]'\\.}>\\),\\\"]")

def urlify2(value):
    return urlfinder.sub(r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', value)
```

call urlify2 on a string and I think that's it if you aren't dealing with a DOM object.

Comment: So, what is not allowed in a url?

Comment: Btw, what if the link is already inside href attribute of an anchor tag?

Comment: When you're inside the text node, make sure the parent or ancestor isn't an anchor.

Comment: @Amarghosh - The coder's regex dictates what a "url" is, of course I agree with you that it's going to be difficult making one that's compatible for all types of urls but even the most basic will support 95% of urls.

Comment: Should the regexp be: `"([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}|((news|telnet|nttp|file|http|ftp|https)://)|(www|ftp)[-A-Za-z0-9]*\\.)[-A-Za-z0-9\\.]+(:[0-9]*)?/[-A-Za-z0-9_\\$\\.\\+\\!\\*\\(\\),;:@&=\\?/~\\#\\%]*[^]'\\.}>\\),\\\"]"`, this one does not compile.

Answer (score 7):

I hunted around a lot, tried these solutions and was not happy with their readability or features, so I rolled the following:

```
_urlfinderregex = re.compile(r'http([^\.\s]+\.[^\.\s]*)+[^\.\s]{2,}')

def linkify(text, maxlinklength):
    def replacewithlink(matchobj):
        url = matchobj.group(0)
        text = unicode(url)
        if text.startswith('http://'):
            text = text.replace('http://', '', 1)
        elif text.startswith('https://'):
            text = text.replace('https://', '', 1)

        if text.startswith('www.'):
            text = text.replace('www.', '', 1)

        if len(text) > maxlinklength:
            halflength = maxlinklength / 2
            text = text[0:halflength] + '...' + text[len(text) - halflength:]

        return '<a class="comurl" href="' + url + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' + text + '<img class="imglink" src="/images/linkout.png"></a>'

    if text != None and text != '':
        return _urlfinderregex.sub(replacewithlink, text)
    else:
        return ''
```

You'll need to get a link out image, but that's pretty easy. This is specifically for user submitted text like comments which I assume is usually what people are dealing with.

Comment: I looked around as well, including a few frameworks that implemented their own linkify function, and I found this one to be the most readable for non-complex purposes.

Comment: This is by far the best regex based text-->HTML script I've found on StackOverflow.  It's significantly better than even the accepted answer.  I only had to change the line `text = unicode(URL)` to `text = str(URL)` for Python 3.x; and remove the link out image.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\w+:\/\/[^\s]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "body of text" do you mean a plain text file, or body text in an HTML document?  If you want the HTML document, you will want to use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse it; then, search through the body text and insert the tags.

Matching the actual URLs is probably best done with the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module.  Full discussion here: [[How do you validate a URL with a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is a lot more open, when it comes to URLs, but it is not always right either. e.g. it will make www.a.b into a hyperlink as well as http://a.b but it often fails because of wrapped text and uncommon (but valid) URL characters.

See [appendix A. A. Collected BNF for URI for syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), and use that to build a reasonable regular expression that will consider what surrounds the URL as well. You'd be well advised to consider a couple of scenarios where URLs might end up.