# dataframe.to_html does not create hyperlinks

Tags: python, pandas

The HTML file that comes out of Dataframe.to_html() does not create hyperlinks when the string content of one of its columns matches an URI.

Is there a way to generate hyperlinks in html docs from a DataFrame?

Comment: perhaps this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727535/replace-urls-in-text-with-links-to-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The `HTMLFormatter` used by `DataFrame.to_html` helps to pretty render a `DataFrame` in a IPython HTML Notebooks I think.

The method does not parse each element of your `DataFrame`, i.e. recognizes an URI pattern to write `<a href="URI">Content</a>` or something else.

I don't think that (1) it's planned and (2) it's not the purpose of this method. Maybe you can add an issue to the [GitHub pandas issues page](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

Answer (score 3):

Setting `escape=False` allows you to input custom html and create hyperlinks as demonstrated below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['url'] = '<a href=' + df['url'] + '><div>' + df['name'] + '</div></a>'
df = df.to_html(escape=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how dynamic your links have to be. I'm currently working on the same issue and tried to solve it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('thead th').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="{% url "cat_view" %}">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');
  });
  $('tbody tr th').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="{% url "date_view" %}">' + $(this).html() + '</a>')
  });
});
```

This makes the headers links, but you could just use it on $('tobdy tr td') if that's what you need. I currently have django url-template tags for the hrefs but you could basically put anything in there. I'm still struggling to correctly construct the href's as soon as they get dynamic (e.g. {% url 'cat_view' cat=category.pk %})