# Turn URL into HTML link

Tags: python, regex, url, formatting

In Python, if I have a URL, what is the simplest way to turn something like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

into:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

So far I have tied a lot with Regular Expressions, but nothing works at all.

Comment: I am downvoting because the example information you provided does not match what you actually wanted for an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace URLs in text with links to URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727535/replace-urls-in-text-with-links-to-urls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> link = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
>>> print('<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(link))
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
>>>
```

Note however that you need to number the format fields since you are repeating an argument.

Comment: What if I have a string containing multiple urls and non-urls?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Could you give an example input/output?

Comment: @Progo This answer meets the criteria as given in the original question.  If your criteria is more complicated then you need to give that information as well.

Comment: input: "Hey bob, go to http://stackexchange.com, they have cool sites like http://stackoverflow.com". The two links would be formatted.

Comment: @SethMMorton This is true. I will accept the answer. I have to wait 2 minutes though

Comment: @Progo - That's significantly different than what you said in your question.  You might be able to use a Regex: `re.sub('(\w+\.com)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', data)` where `data` is your input string.  Of course, this is a very simple solution.  You will probably want to make the pattern a lot more robust. That, or look into libraries designed to work with HTML or URLs.

Comment: @iCodez Sorry... I didn't phrase the question as well as I would like to have. Your solution works very well. Thanks!

Comment: @iCodez this will not work with links that do not end with `.com` or that specify a sub resource: `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28641210` EDIT: looks like i read over the second statement of your comment.

Comment: not working for urls like `http://my?param1&param2`

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "http://stackoverflow.com www.foo.com"
>>> re.sub(r'\b((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^\s.]+\.)+\w{2,4})\b', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', s)
'<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> <a href="www.foo.com">www.foo.com</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, but iCodez deserves the excepted answer. Thanks though.

Comment: seems like you're trying to search and replace  links in  an input string within a tag.

Comment: Correct. As I said, your answer works, but since I didn't phrase my original question very well and iCodez answered the original question **and** answered this one in a comment, he deserves the accept. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library to convert URL to HTML  tag, e.g. [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linkify.html):

```py
from bleach import linkify
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com?with=param1&other=param2'
atag = linkify(url)
print(atag)
```

will output

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com?with=param1&amp;other=param2" rel="nofollow">https://stackoverflow.com?with=param1&amp;other=param2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
reference = '<a href=\"'+ url + '\">' + url + '</a>'
```

Comment: No, I don't know what the link is. I string and each url needs to be formatted.

Comment: iCodez answer is better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have that string in a variable, or can get it, I'd suggest you use `string.format`.

```
link = '<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'
stackOverflowLink = link.format("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

`stackOverflowLink` will then contain
`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>`